PyQt6 QComboBox: How to Start with Placeholder Size and Expand to Largest Item?
I have this Combo Box:
luch_list = QComboBox(parent=self)
luch_list.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Policy.Fixed)
luch_list.setMinimumWidth(10)
luch_list.setPlaceholderText('Luch')
luch_list.addItem('steak with french fries')
luch_list.addItem('chicken and broccoli')

My Place holder text is obviously shorter than my Combo Box items so initially the Combo Box looks like this:

However, I want my Combo Box list to look like this initially:

but then expand when the user selects one of the options like so:

I've tried adding the following statements but it did not worked:
# Set the initial size based on the placeholder text
lunch_list.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QComboBox.SizeAdjustPolicy.AdjustToContents)


See minimumContentsLength and the related AdjustToMinimumContentsLengthWithIcon size adjust policy. Alternatively, get the sizeHint() as soon as the placeholder is set and before adding items, then call setMaximumWidth() with it. Finally, connect to the currentIndexChanged signal to unset the policy in the first case, or reset the maximum width (with 16777215) if the index is >= 0.

You're welcome. I suggest you to answer your own question by clicking the related button down on this page, briefly explaining what you did and providing a proper [mre].
